# socket timed out for session Selenium-Hub/Node-Chrome Docker containers

Tags: python, selenium, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Running the following services in a stack via `docker-compose`:

- `jenkins/jnlp-slave` 
  (custom built, to include pip3, python3, some other jazz)   replicated 1 / 1
- `selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59` replicated 12 / 12
- `selenium/hub:3.141.59` replicated 1 / 1

I'm running BDD tests kicked off via Jenkins, all spin up a remote webdriver session.

Most of my tests are running just fine but a few of them return the following error (this is in the logs of the `selenium-hub` container:

```
ERROR [RequestHandler.process] - Socket timed out for session ext. key xxxxx , timeout
```

Console output of job:

```
Exception WebDriverException: Message: Session [cxxxxxxxx] was terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions.getExistingSession (ActiveTestSessions.java:115)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry.getExistingSession (DefaultGridRegistry.java:387)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.getSession (RequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:123)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doGet (DriverServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:503)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask (EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run (EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/behave", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 109, in main
    failed = runner.run()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 672, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 693, in run_with_paths
    return self.run_model()
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 483, in run_model
    failed = feature.run(self)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 523, in run
    failed = scenario.run(runner)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1255, in run
    failed = scenario.run(runner)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure_commons/_allure.py", line 180, in __call__
    return self._test(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 882, in run
    if not step.run(runner):
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1510, in run
    runner.run_hook('after_step', runner.context, self)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 405, in run_hook
    self.hooks[name](context, *args)
  File "Behave/features/environment.py", line 126, in after_step
    allure.attach(context.browser.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(),
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 943, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 953, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Session [xxxxxxx2] was terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions.getExistingSession (ActiveTestSessions.java:115)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry.getExistingSession (DefaultGridRegistry.java:387)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.getSession (RequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:123)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:85)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doGet (DriverServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:503)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask (EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run (EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Seems to be an intermittent issue. Other than running a different tag for `node-chrome` and `selenium/hub` images, I haven't found a solution. Or even a reason as to why this is occurring.

Please advise!

Comment: maybe you don't have enough resources in your PC

Comment: @c4f4t0r all these tests are running to containers running on a swarm comprised of 5 linux boxes with like 60 GB + of memory and 40 CPU. So i don't think it's a resource issue

Comment: you already checked all swarm machines? there is no unlimited resources in the world, if you have a socket timeout you need to start to check in your infra, call it server or pc, but the sense is the same.

Comment: Thanks @c4f4t0r i checked the machines, performance of servers at run-time, nothing abnormal. 

I think i found the issue though. Doing some investigating and will answer my own question. _VERY_ random issue, but seems to be resolved.

Comment: :) I am glad that you solved and I will be happy to see what was the issue.

Comment: What is, then, the answer to this problem @partydog?

Comment: @partydog: I am facing similar issue. Can you please post your solution? Thanks